# how to send response from server to client using python socket?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

i want to communication between two system using python socket, in which one machine is local system(client) and another is public system(server),

the code i write is :

client.py

```
import socket
import commands
import sys
import time


s = socket.socket()
state = sys.argv[1]

pname = sys.argv[2]
user = commands.getoutput("whoami")
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('132.65.45.156', 5001))


info = commands.getoutput("echo '%s','%s','%s','%s'"%(state,ip,user,pname))
while True:
   data2 = info
   s.sendall(data2)
break
```

server.py

```
import socket
import time
import string
import sys
import base64


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('', 5001))
sock.listen(5)

while True:
newSocket, address = sock.accept()
print "Connected from ", address
filename = newSocket.recv(5001) 
while True:     
data = newSocket.recv(5001)     
if not data: break
print filename, "Received\n"
sock.close()
```

After getting response from client to server, what to do if server want to send response to client ?

Comment: Add `newSocket.send('my response')` to the server, and `response = s.recv(1024)` to the client.

Comment: See my previous comment, i can't explain it any better